# JSoup Add Wrapper div after body

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to add a `<div class="wrapper">` to my generated html after the body tag. I want the ending `</div>` to be before the ending `</body>`. So far I have

```
private String addWrapper(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element e = doc.select("body").first().appendElement("div");
    e.attr("class", "wrapper");

    return doc.toString();
}
```

and I am getting

```
 </head>
  <body>
   &lt;/head&gt;  
  <p>Heyo</p>   
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also can't figure out why I am getting "</head>" in the html too. I only get it when I use JSoup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jsoup Document normalizes the text with normalise method. [The method is here in Document class.](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.java#L113) So It wraps with  and  tags.

In Jsoup.parse() method it can take three parameter, parse(String html, String baseUri, Parser parser);

We will give the parser parameter as Parser.xmlParser which is using XMLTreeBuilder (Otherwise it uses HtmlTreeBuilder and it normalises html.).

I tried, latest code (it may be optimize) :

```
  String html = "<body>&lt;/head&gt;<p>Heyo</p></body>";

  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

  Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
  attributes.put("class","wrapper");

  Element e = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "", attributes);
  e.html(doc.select("body").html());

  doc.select("body").html(e.toString());

  System.out.println(doc.toString());
```